# Twilio Programable Chat Rest API Accepting JSON

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

When creating a Channel the REST API seems to ignore any data in requests with a JSON body. Example:

```
curl -X POST https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/{instance sid}/Channels -H 'authorization: Basic blah blah blah' -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{ "friendly_name": "Test Chat One", "type": "private" }'
```

Does the API not support JSON requests? The docs show requests with post with form data https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest/channels?code-sample=code-create-a-channel&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=default but not JSON??

Have I missed something?

Ta

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio API does not support JSON requests (though it will respond with JSON if you ask it to).

Check [the documentation on the API here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/request#post). It says:

> In the PUT or POST, you represent the properties of the object you wish to update as form urlencoded key/value pairs. Don't worry, this is already the way browsers encode POSTs by default. But be sure to set the HTTP Content-Type header to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" for your requests if you are writing your own client.